# Which is faster? Multiple tables or multiple rows for sporadic select on timeseries postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I need help making a high level decision on how to proceed with postgresql application.

Data structure:

The data is time-series data generated in real time over the last 10 years, delineated with days since epoch/HH/MM/SS timestamps (in the order of about 100 million rows).

Desired Operation:

- The selects will call for either a specific row from all the data or where rows (list) falls between two timestamps on a specific day since epoch. -Data is generated everyday and is known: newer data will be called more than older data.
- Multiple clients/selects will be running concurrently (order of 10000 queries/minute) assume hardware capable.
- Each query is unique

For a given(fixed) capable hardware setup, which is faster? And what's the O() time? given N rows?

1. Having a single large table (millions of rows)?
2. Splitting table up by day since epoch 3000 (day_since_epoch)tables with thousands of rows)?

Comment: You might want to partition the table by timestamp period.

Comment: You might want to consider the timescaleDb extension that manages table partitioning

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up (partitioning) the table per day will result in too many partitions. That will slow down query planning time considerably.

An index range scan is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of rows in the result set, regardless if the table is partitioned or not.

Partitioning a large table can have benefits, but index scans will even become slower (instead of a single index, several may have to be scanned).